# Implementation dependent-type

Tags: c++, c++17

when I start to look the library about boost; I see some typedef as follows:

```
 using size_type              = /* implementation-defined */;
```

or something like

```
typedef implementation_define iterator;
```

how can I understand the expression here.
In my basic knowledge the typedef expression should be like this

```
typedef typeA typeB; // typeB is alias of typeA
```

Comment: What is it? C++11 or c++17? "_how can I understand the expression here_" - Only by reading `boost` code. The point with `/* implementation-defined */` is that you should not need to worry. Even the standard C++ library is filled with these gems.

Comment: Do you know why `auto` became so popular so fast? Because often, the exact type doesn't matter. Or is at least far too inconvenient to name, even using typedefs. The only things of importance are existence of the type, and interface (operations and their behavior, member-types as applicable, ...). Often, to preserve implementers freedom to choose the best path, that is also the only thing specified about things in the standard library. Sometimes even though it looks like more is specified. See among others "addressable function", "customization point object", and <cheader>/<header.h>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I understand the expression here

You aren't meant to; that's why the comment is there.

Boost documentation is often written like pages from the C++ standard: not so much documentation as a specification of *behavior*.

What is specified is how a system behaves. If some behavior of the system is defined to be "implementation-dependent", then what that means is that you're not really able to rely on its *exact* nature.

`size_type` is some type that provides some set of required behavior, as laid down elsewhere in the documentation. The *exact* type used may vary from compiler to compiler. Maybe in one compiler, it is `unsigned int`; on another, its `unsigned long long`. And that's OK; you don't need to care *exactly* what type it is. Only that it's a type that behaves as the docs say.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.  how can I know that size_type should be unsigned int or unsigned long long based on my complier, is there any explicit statement? BTW: do you know is there any document can introduce this concept" unspecified,  implementation-defined" better?

Comment: @yiluo: You aren't supposed to *care* about the exact type of `size_type`. It should not matter to your code at all whether it is `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`. If you to create a variable of this type, you use the `size_type` alias you have been given.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I understand the expression here.

The expression means that `size_type` and in the latter example `iterator` are aliases of **some** types which have been omitted from the documentation, and that the types depend on the language implementation, and that in the latter case that type conforms to the Iterator concept.

Comment: so can I understand that there maybe exist some omitted type(Assume X) which conforms the iterator concept, so  this expression implicitly means typedef X iterator?

Comment: @yiluo Yes it does.